# LFTP exclude specific folder only

Tags: lftp

I have same folder name in different sub-directories, but while mirroring I want to exclude specific folder only.

Example :

I have directory "123" in different directories

```
./abc/123/
./abc/xyz/123/
./xxx/123/
./abc/yyy/123/
```

I want to exclude `./abc/123/` only, but if I use below command that exclude all occurance

```
lftp  -p 22 -e 'mirror --exclude ./abc/123/ './abc' '/var/www/' ; exit' sftp://user@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If `^\` is specified, only the top level seems to be excluded.

Example :

```
home/
　├ img/
　│　└ dummyA.png
　└ upload/
　 　└ img/
　 　 　└ dummyB.png
```

In case of the above directory structure

```
mirror --reverse -x ^\img/ --delete /home /site
```

```
site/
　└ upload/
　 　└ img/
　 　 　└ dummyB.png
```